# creating a mailing list subscribe form present on every page without refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, mailing-list

I would like to create a form that is present on every page. It a simple form so that users can register their email address. So my question is, rather than putting an instance in of '    @mailer = MailingList.new' in every controller, would I use my application controller so that it covers the whole site? This is what I have tried to do

application controller

```
  def mail_list
    @mailer = MailingList.new
  end
```

header.html.erb

```
    <% form_for @mailer do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <% end %>
```

and i encounter the error

```
undefined method `mail_list_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000103433240>:0x0000010166fc68>
```

I think I understand why. I also realise there is no 'save' method in my controller, so even if the page was to load it wouldn't work on submission, but I would at least have expected the form to appear. What is the most conventional way to achieve this? where am i going wrong?

**As an extra:**
It would be preferable that on form submission the page does not refresh, that the data is submitted to the db via Ajax. Can anyone point me to a good tutorial, or guide to explain how this works and how I could implement it.

I am new to rails and so apologies for the possibly poor explanation and thanks for your time.

Comment: Your error is route related, what do you have on `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: @nicooga i aded this,   get '/', to: 'application#mail_list'